# JTextPane won't display text added by DefaultStyledDocument

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

Okay I've the following problem, I write a simple graphical chat client with the Java Swing Framework. For displaying the received messages I use a `JTextPane`. I had the problem that when one user sends a message out of single character without any blanks, the `JTextPane` component doesn't wrap the line. I solved this issue with the following code, now the `JTextPane` component don't wrap only by word boundaries, also at any character if the length don't fit the width of the component.

```
public class WrapEditorKit extends StyledEditorKit
{
    ViewFactory defaultFactory;

    public WrapEditorKit()
    {
        this.defaultFactory = new WrapColumnFactory();
    }

    public ViewFactory getViewFactory()
    {
        return this.defaultFactory;
    }

}

class WrapLabelView extends LabelView
{
    public WrapLabelView(Element element)
    {
        super(element);
    }

    public float getMinimumSpan(int axis)
    {
        switch(axis)
        {
            case View.X_AXIS:
            {
                return 0;
            }
            case View.Y_AXIS:
            {
                return super.getMinimumSpan(axis);
            }
            default:
            {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid axis: " + axis);
            }
        }
    }
}

class WrapColumnFactory implements ViewFactory
{
    public View create(Element element)
    {
        String kind = element.getName();

        if(null != kind)
        {
            if(kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ContentElementName))
            {
                return new WrapLabelView(element);
            }
            else if(kind.equals(AbstractDocument.ParagraphElementName))
            {
                return new ParagraphView(element);
            }
            else if(kind.equals(AbstractDocument.SectionElementName))
            {
                return new BoxView(element, View.Y_AXIS);
            }
            else if(kind.equals(StyleConstants.ComponentElementName))
            {
                return new ComponentView(element);
            }
            else if(kind.equals(StyleConstants.IconElementName))
            {
                return new IconView(element);
            }
        }

        return new LabelView(element);
    }
}
```

I got this code for a long time from a web page, I don't have any URL, I it works great for a small text edit panel. But when I add text over a `Document` like above it displays nothing, it works only if I type the words directly in the pane, but not when I add text over a method of the `Document` class...

```
StyleContext msgPaneStyle = new StyleContext();
final DefaultStyledDocument msgPaneDocument = new DefaultStyledDocument(this.msgPaneStyle);
JTextPane msgPane = new JTextPane(msgPaneDocument);
msgPane.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());
```

If I add text now by typing..

```
msgPaneDocument.insertString(msgPaneDocument.getLength(), text, null);
```

...it doesn't work (Doesn't display the text), without the editor kit it works. Any ideas or hints?

**EDIT**

I think the problem is, that my custom `EditorKit` and the `StyledDocument` don't work at same time... If I insert text by typing `msgPane.setText(text)` it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved/prevented this issue myself. When I'm using...

```
JTextPane msgPane = new JTextPane();
msgPane.setEditorKit(new WrapEditorKit());

msgPane.getDocument().insertString(msgPane.getDocument().getLength(), text, null);
```

...it works, also with highlighting of single words! I don't add a custom `DefaultStyledDocument` this time, instead I used the `Document` returned by `msgPane.getDocument()` and now it works.

*If there are any other solutions, specially with using of a custom `DefaultStyledDocument` or any explanations for this issue I would be glad...*